# Redirect on controller advice expectionhandler with model attribute spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So i try to redirect from ExceptionHandler wit model attribute to the site where it was caused.

For example i have a controller method witch list the current items:

```
@AvailableInMenu
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("Companys", iCompanyService.findAll().getData());
    return "masters/crud/company/list";
}
```

An this is the template witch the method call:

```
    <div th:if="${exception != null}" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Warning!</strong><div th:text="${exception}" th:remove="tag" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th th:text="#{app.maintanance.installversion}"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="company : ${Companys}">
                        <td th:text="${company.installversion}"></td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="delete-button" th:attr="data-redir=@{/company/delete/{id}(id = ${company.id})}">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This thymeleaf code generate a table with data and a delete link. Th entity wotch the user use has foreign key, and if the user want to delete it jpa thows a foreign key constraint witch i wrap into an error wrapper.

This is the controller method for the delete link:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/delete/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteCompany(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    ErrorWrapper<Boolean> result = iCompanyService.deleteCompany(id);
    if(result.hasError()){
        if(result.getConstraint()){
            throw new GlobalModelException(601L, "redirect:/company");
        }
    }
    return "redirect:/company";
}
```

AS you can see if there was an error i throw general exception that i create, and a ControllerAdvice with ExpectonHandler where is catch my expection class. I want to add the exception to model and redirect back to the listing site, and show the bootstrap alert to the on the site.
This is the exceptionHandler from the ControllerAdvice

```
@ExceptionHandler(GlobalModelException.class)
public ModelAndView handlingException(GlobalModelException exception) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName(exception.getUrl());
    model.addObject("exception", exception);
    return model;
}
```

The ModelAndView redirect me the correct place as it should be, but the exception is null after redirect. How can i call my listing site with the exception in the model with ControllerADvice. I have many other exceptions that i want to handle and a a lot of other controller where i need this.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A redirect cannot have a model. You will have to use flash attributes. Also are you certain yu want to use a GET request for a deletion action? Use a DELETE or a POST instead...

Comment: since there is role based access control in spring delete with get is pretty safe and in a @ExceptionHandler you cant use flashattributa lik in controllers. That was the first thin i think about

Comment: I would say it isn't , but alas and I would use a DELETE or POST (as that is also good practice for data modification). Then stick the stuff in the session instead of the model. Also I think using Exceptions to control the flow is something you shouldn't do in the first place, but imho that is.

Comment: Well, and how should i do? I think the most simple way to handle key duplication foregin key constraint, login error, and some else is to throw an error, with some and and handle with exception handler. You have to catch this errors, and once it' catched why souldn't use is?

Comment: I nowhere said you shouldn't handle those exceptions, but using another exception for that is something you shouldn't do, that is the flow control I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You mush use RedirectAttributes/FlashAttribute.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward

Comment: ModelAndView dosen't have  RedirectAttributes/FlashAttribute, and since @ExceptionHandler not a controller as you can see, @ExceptionHandler(GlobalModelException.class)
public ModelAndView handlingException(GlobalModelException exception, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes ) {...}
 dosen't work either